# Get next and previous in sql with a loop

Tags: php, sql

A topic has images attached. I use these two queries to be able to open the previous and next image with a link. When you get to the last picture, you only have the option to get to the previous one and when you get to the first, you can only go to the next one. However, it wants to have a loop. This means when you get to the last one and you click on next, the first one will be loaded and when you get to the first and keep clicking on before, the last one will be loaded. I think a "loop" described it very well.

Is this possible with SQL in a simple query?

**previous SQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE 
attach_id < 9580 
AND topic_id = 109331
ORDER BY attach_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**previous PHP:**

```
while ($prevrow = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{
$previd  = $prevrow['attach_id'];
}
```

**next SQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE 
attach_id > 9580 
AND topic_id = 109331
ORDER BY attach_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**next PHP:**

```
while ($nextrow = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{
$nextid  = $nextrow['attach_id'];
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure I completely get this but you can opt for select * of all attachments and then use any frontend datatable like jquery datatable for previous and next buttons.

Comment: If your "previous" query did not find any record, then you want to go and select the record with the _highest_ attach_id instead. And if your "next" query doesn't find any, then you want to go and select that with the _lowest_.

Comment: (And you could stop using while loops to fetch the result of queries that can _at most_ return one record. What's the point of _looping_ in such a case?)

Comment: @CBroe I had that in mind but then I need 4 queries instead of maybe one?

Comment: You will hardly be able to get the data for both "directions" in one single query. But you could use a UNION statement to implement the additions I mentioned to each of your existing statements - and then you take the _first_ record out of that UNION result. If you found a previous record for the current one without "wrapping around", then the first record will contain that; otherwise, there will _be_ only one result record with the highest attachment id. And vice versa for the other direction.